# Does anyone know the book "The Eagle Flies Over England"?

Tags: alternate-history, story-identification

In 1969, visiting my aunt in the Netherlands, I saw and read a book in her library which I seem to recall was titled *The Eagle Flies over England*. It supposes that the Buonoparte family fled Corsica for England in 1769, resulting in a certain Napoleone of that family being raised as a minor English (guest) noble.

Demonstrating his artillery and leadership skills early, Napoleone succeeds in defeating the French Republic forces repeatedly and enters Paris  a *French hero* for ending *The Terror*. One thing leads to another and another, and by December 5, 1805, we have almost merged our fantasy and historical threads, which finally merge completely on June 18, 1815, on a field of battle near the Belgian villages of *Mont St. Jean* and *La Belle Alliance*.

The book was printed in English, and I have no recollection of it being a translation. My Aunt, as is common for educated Western Europeans, spoke and read good English, French and German in addition to her native Dutch, and had books from all four of those languages on her bookshelves.

Has anyone else heard of this book? I have Googled it several times over the past several years, an cannot find any evidence of it. It was likely a British printing, if not also a British publication, that I encountered in her library. If yes, do you have an author's name and accurate title?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"The Eagle Flies from England" by Edward Atiyah (published 1960)– What if Charles and Letizia Bonaparte fled to Britain in 1769 and Napoleon was born a British subject?

mentioned on [this page about alternate Napoleons](http://shannonselin.com/2014/11/napoleon-alternate-history/)